# Binary search tree insert method not working

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value = None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class binary_search_tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self,current,value):
        if current == None:
            current = Node(value)
        elif value < current.value:
            self.insert(current.left,value)
        elif value > current.value:
            self.insert(current.right,value)

tree = binary_search_tree()
for i in (12,5,18,3,4,6):
    tree.insert(tree.root,i)
```

The insert method for my binary search tree is not working can someone help me out.

(Post is mostly code, please add more details.)

Comment: Don't you need to create your tree before inserting values on it?

Comment: @davidbuzatto I did create a a tree, sorry i did not include it in the code block above

Comment: You might want to consider how `self.root` can ever change when you never assign it a value other than `None`. And if `self.root` is always `None`, you'll never be able to add items.

Comment: @Dukeling I figured that might be the problem, any idea how should i approach this differently?

Comment: `current = Node(value)` will change only the local variable and leave the thing you're passing in unchanged. Related: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006) Or you can just return the thing you want to change it to and put the assignment outside of the function (e.g. `current.left = self.insert(current.left,value)`).